# Crypto in JavaScript and its equivalent in C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Kindly ignore my understanding with following code as I've no or limited knowledge with JS. Could anyone help understanding as what's happening in the last bit of the code: `digest('hex')`

Code:

```
const payloadHash = crypto
  .createHmac('sha1', secret)
  .update(request.body)
  .digest('hex');
```

As far as I could understand, it's creating a HMAC with SHA1 algorithm, but not sure of `digest('hex')`. What would be C# equivalent of the same or how to replicate the same in C#. I'd want to achieve the same in C#.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `C#` equivalent. See [ComputeHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithm-computehash(system-byte())) and [hmac.digest](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#hmacdigestencoding) for more information.

```cs
HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secret);
byte[] payloadHash = hmac.ComputeHash(request.body);
```